# WARNING: [youtube] Cannot parse localized time text

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Решил добавить в своего бота музыку, скачал [вот этот код](https://github.com/pawel02/music_bot/blob/main/music_cog.py) для того, чтобы добавить к уже имеющимся функциям. Библиотека youtube_dl работать не захотела, вместо неё использовал yt_dpl, одна проблема ушла, но, появилась новая. При запросе песни в голосовом канале, бот подключается, пытается воспроизвести звук из видео и на этом крашится. Вот, что происходит в консоли:

```
[youtube:search] Extracting URL: ytsearch:never gonna give you up
[download] Downloading playlist: never gonna give you up
[youtube:search] query "never gonna give you up": Downloading web client config
[youtube:search] query "never gonna give you up" page 1: Downloading API JSON
[youtube:search] Playlist never gonna give you up: Downloading 1 items of 1
[download] Downloading item 1 of 1
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading m3u8 information
WARNING: [youtube] Cannot parse localized time text "Oct 25, 2009"
[download] Finished downloading playlist: never gonna give you up
[2023-07-11 18:27:45] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Connecting to voice...
[2023-07-11 18:27:45] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Starting voice handshake... 
(connection attempt 1)
[2023-07-11 18:27:45] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Voice handshake complete. 
Endpoint found russia9955.discord.media
[2023-07-11 18:27:46] [INFO    ] discord.player: ffmpeg process 10908 successfully 
terminated with return code of 3221225781.
```

Активное гугление результатов не дало. Понимаю, что не может запарсить дату, но как это исправить в душе не чаю